# ffmpeg command does not work when run from .sh file

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run an ffmpeg command from a shell file but I am getting the following error :

```
'NULL @ 0x343e9c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '
```

: Invalid argument

Below the  ffmpeg commnad

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:adminCTZSDS@192.168.0.5/1" -s 600x400 -framerate 20 -b:v 16k -preset slow -acodec libmp3lame -ar 11025 -crf 20 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/camara2
```

and this is the content of the shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script streaming
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://admin:adminCTZSDS@192.168.0.5/1" -s 600x400 -framerate 20 -b:v 16k -preset slow -acodec libmp3lame -ar 11025 -crf 20 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/camara2
```

the command works if I run it manually in a terminal

Comment: Check your file for DOS-style carriage returns

Comment: thank Jochen, finally I found the error at the end of the command had a empty space which generated error